# Calculating Big O notation for stack problem using pointer

Tags: c++, stack, big-o

Hi can anyone help me to count the algorithmic complexity of this code using Big O notation? I'm not too understand in using Big O because so there are many pointers in this code. I just know some of the code. Like cout is O(1). The rest i don't understand. I'm just a beginner at programming. Please help me to count the big o notation. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class Book {
    int year, page;
    unsigned long long int code;
    string language, name, title;
    Book *head, *next, *prev, *link;

public:
    Book (string & name, string & title, unsigned long long int code, string & language, int year, int page) {
        head = NULL;
        this->name = name;
        this->title = title;
        this->language = language;
        this->code = code;
        this->year = year;
        this->page = page;
    }

    ~Book (void) {
        delete head;
    }

    void display (void);
    void add (void);
    void dellete (void);
};

void Book::add(void) {
    string name, title, language;
    int year, page;
    unsigned long long int code;
    cout << "Add a book...";
    cout << endl << "Author\t\t:", cin >> name;
    cout << "Title\t\t:", cin >> title;
    cout << "ISBN(13 digits)\t:", cin >> code;
    cout << "Language\t:", cin >> language;
    cout << "Year\t\t:", cin >> year;
    cout << "Pages\t\t:", cin >> page;

    Book* p = new Book(name, title, code, language, year, page);
    p->next = head;
    head = p;
}

void Book::dellete(void) {
    string name, title, language;
    int year, page;
    unsigned long long int code;
    Book* p, *prev, *next;

    if(head==NULL) {
        cout << "There is no book in the stack\n";
    } else if(head->next==NULL) {
        p = head;
        head = NULL;
        free(p);
        cout << "All book has been taken. Now the stack is empty\n";
    } else{
        p = head;
        head = p->next;
        free(p);
        cout << "A book has been taken\n";
    }
}

void Book::display(void) {
    Book* p = head;
    cout << "Displaying book(s)...\n";
    while (p) {
        cout << "----------------------------- \n";
        cout << "Author\t\t:" << p->name << endl;
        cout << "Title\t\t:" << p->title << endl;
        cout << "ISBN\t\t:" << p->code << endl;
        cout << "Language\t:" << p->language << endl;
        cout << "Year\t\t:" << p->year << endl;
        cout << "Pages\t\t:" << p->page << endl;
        cout << endl;
        p = p->next;
    }
}

int main (int argc, char const** argv) {
    string blank = "";
    Book* B = new Book(blank, blank, 0, blank, 0, 0);
    int opt;
    for (;;) {
        cout << "----------------------------- \n";
        cout << "1) Add a book.\n";
        cout << "2) Show all books.\n";
        cout << "3) Take a book\n";
        cout << "4) Exit. \n";
        cout << "Don't use space but use underscore...\n\n";

        cout << "Options:", cin >> opt;
        switch (opt) {
            case 1:
                B->add();
                break;
            case 2:
                B->display();
                break;
            case 3:
                B->dellete();
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
            default:
                continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which part of it? A program doesn’t have a defined complexity, an algorithm has.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the most i don't understand in this part

Comment: `if(head==NULL){
    cout << "There is no book in the stack\n";
}
else if(head->next==NULL){
    p = head;
    head = NULL;
    free(p);
    cout << "All book has been taken. Now the stack is empty\n";
}
else{
    p = head;
    head = p->next;
    free(p);
    cout << "A book has been taken\n";
}
}`

Comment: and what about the `for(;;)` is it O(n) ?? Because it'll never end until we exit the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The O-Notation classifies an algorithm in how complex it gets (in means of e.g. runtime or memory usage) dependent on the size of the problem. So O(1) means no matter how big the problem is, the algorithm doesn't grow in complexity, no matter how big this constant cost is.

Let's view some of your program parts.

**Delete**

This has a runtime complexity of **O(1)**, because no matter how big the stack of Books is, it is always nearly the same amount of operations you do for deleting the top of the book stack. The only difference is between 0, 1 and 2 books, but if you grow the stack to infinity the amount of operations doesn't grow, and that is what matters.

**Add**

It is difficult to measure here. Since this method only adds 1 book at a time it is **O(1)**, because no matter how many books there are already (it's the only variable size) you need always the same amount of operations. It would be more interesting if you would allow adding multiple books at once.

**Display**

So display prints out all the books on the stack. If you grow the amount of books the number of operations also arises. Now the question is in what manner? In this case doubling the amount of books doubles the amount of instructions. This is a linear growth and thus the complexity class is **O(n)**.

---

It can be helpful to view the loop count. One loop over the problem size often does mean O(n). If you have two nested loops (over the problem size) you often have O(n²) and so on.

To your question what the endless loop in your main function is, well it depends on what you define as your problem size, I don't know if it makes sense to measure it here.

If you define the number of user actions in total as problem size it gets complicated. If we let out the display part and only allow add and delete, it is O(n), because everything would be constant (since add and delete are O(1) and the other things are independent instructions like cout) and they occur in a loop based on the problem size n (the number of user actions). If you take display into account, it isn't that simple, because display has an O(m) complexity (m = Number of books) and this is highly dependant on the actual user input which was given before. I don't know what would be the complexity there.

Comment: how about the `for(;;)` it repeats everytime unless we exit the program, what is the big O?

Comment: It is in the last paragraph of my answer. It depends on what you define the problem size.

Comment: So we must define how much is the amount of the stack? @birdfreeyahoo

Comment: No you have to define what the problem size is. For example, when you try to determine O of a sorting algorithm, the problem size is the size of the list you want to sort. Because with this O you want to see how the cost of the algorithm changes when you change the problem size. What is the problem size you want to have the O-function of? You must have some use for it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what that means. What can I do to define the problem size.

Comment: You have to find out what it is. Why you want the O of this input loop? It makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: what about the switch case? Is it O(log n)?

Comment: Again, you have to define a problem size. Please take some time first understanding the O-notation. Then you will be able to give a proper problem definition, or understand why it is not necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer I really appreciate your answer. @birdfreeyahoo

Comment: @S.H.431405 I edited my last paragraph to try and give you an O for the for loop

Comment: Thank you again @birdfreeyahoo your answer is very helpfull